# Drupal module to redirect anonymous users to specific path causes redirection loop

Tags: php, drupal

Ok so I have some semi working code, so lets start there:

```
function anonredirect_init() {
     global $user;
     if (!in_array($_GET['q'], array('anonymous','admin')) && !$user->uid) {
        drupal_goto('anonymous');
     }
}
```

The jist is the content within Drupal is subscription based and anonymous users have to go and either login or sign up.

I have confirmed that my check to see if I have an anonymous user is correct. The problem is after the redirect to /anonymous (path module is enabled) I get a redirect loop error. I thought by specifying the paths not to redirect on would solve this error however my theory seems to be wrong.

I am on Drupal 6 and have clean URLs enabled. Just in case this is on CentOS/PHP5/LAMP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure anonymous isn't resolved to something else by a path alias or mod_rewrite?

Comment: anonymous is aliased. anonymous -> node/59. I thought that aliasing would not interfere - shows my poor Drupal knowledge.

Comment: You were dead on. For the record I had to use "node/59". Thanks for your help!